# How to describe dihedral angle between two planes? front view and side view included angles of intersecions?

Tags: geometry, angle

Two planes are intersecting by certain dihedral angle. Assuming one plane is superimposed on `XY` plane, the second plane is intersecting by certain amount of pitching and rolling (not perpendicular or aligned to any original Cartesian plane). if I know the coordinates of the three points related to each plane and I know the dihedral angle between them, how can I describe the angle?

The dihedral angle is always coming as absolute value (not - or + that indicate direction)

```
normalPlane1=zeros(size(Plane1_P3,1),size(Plane1_P3,2));
for i=1:size(Plane1_P3,1)
normalPlane1(i,:)=cross(Plane1_P1(i,:)-Plane1_P2(i,:),Plane1_P1(i,:)-    Plane1_P3(i,:),2);
end
normalPlane2=zeros(size(Plane2_P3,1),size(Plane2_P3,2));
for i=1:size(Plane2_P3,1)
normalPlane2(i,:)=cross(Plane2_P1(i,:)-Plane2_P2(i,:),Plane2_P1(i,:)-   Plane2_P3(i,:),2);
end

v1=normalPlane1;
v2=normalPlane2;

a=zeros(20,3);
b=zeros(20,1);
vecNorm3d=zeros(20,1);
thetaPlane1_Plane2=zeros(20,1);
for i=1:20
a(i,:)=cross(v1(i,:),v2(i,:),2);
b(i)=dot(v1(i,:),v2(i,:),2);
vecNorm3d(i)=sqrt(sum(a(i,:).*a(i,:),2));
thetaPlane1_Plane2(i)=atan2(vecNorm3d(i),b(i));

end
```

If for instance the angle was 30 degrees, how it should look?

Should we describe it as three included angles from 
1) perpendicular view to XY plane 
2) perpendicular view to XZ plane and 
3) perpendicular view to YZ plane ?

Comment: Why do you need anything more to "describe" angle? Just take arccos of the dot product of normalized normals. What is real problem?

Comment: Thank you for the comment and question.

I have the normal vectors, the 3 points for both of the planes and I have the dihedral angle value between them. 
I made regression models to predict one plane by using the other plane and independent predictors.
so when I have the predicted angle, I need to describe what is the new plane look like or how it is related to the 1st plane.
I need this for for application on my study 
I need to compare the predicted and the existing planed in new independent sample